# Java and polymorphism

Tags: java, multithreading, process, polymorphism

I'm just having a bad day with Java, because it seems not to understand polymorphism. I try to call the methods : up() and down(), in this simple exercise, and it says: method.up() is undefined for the type Semaphore. I don't know what went wrong there!

```
public class MutexThread extends Thread
{
     private Semaphore mutex;
     private int value;

     public MutexThread(Semaphore Mutex, String name)
     {
         super(name);
         start();
      }

     public synchronized void down() throws InterruptedException 
     {
         while (value == 0)
         {
             wait();
         }
         value-- ;

     }

     public synchronized void up()
     {
         value ++;
         notify();
     }

    public void run()
     {
         while(true)
         {
             mutex.down();
             System.out.println("Enter critical section" +getName());
             try
             {
                 sleep((int)(Math.random()*100));
             }
             catch(InterruptedException e) {}
             System.out.println("Leave critical section" +getName());
             mutex.up();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Java [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) doesn't have an ```up``` method. Try acquire maybe?

Comment: You're calling ```up``` on the variable mutex, which is of type Semaphore. Your up method is defined in ```MutexThread```, so you might wanna make an object of that type.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Eclipse not understanding things isn't the problem here.

Comment: How about removing `mutex.` from these method calls? And if this works, please think abou _why_ it works now.

Comment: I tried, and it works now, Tom! Thank you very much. I think it's because the method I was calling is contained inside my own class, and not in Semaphore class, as many people here are suggesting as well. It was just unclear to me how polymorphism worked in this case. Thanks anyway

Comment: 9/10 times when compiler does not understand some concept, it is because you don't understand it either.

Answer (score 1):

the method `up` is defined in the class **MutexThread**  and **not** in javas built-in Semaphore.
try `this.up()` instead of `mutex.up()`.